# What happens to the USB after burning Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: usb

If my host is Windows 7 and I want to try Ubuntu using a bootable USB, will I be able to use the USB for just storage or would it be forever a bootable for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You can format the drive (or delete all the contents) & can use it as usual.

Even when ubuntu files are there, you can use rest of the space.

Answer (score 0):

The rest of your storage is still avaiable for you, and you always can format the USB if you don't want the bootable anymore